# Online payment - trigger on event

Tags: stripe-payments, payment-gateway, payment-processing

Im looking for some advice in relation to a solution that allows a payment to be triggered on a specific event, automatically.

- Step 1: User signs up to make a charity donation (provides banking information)
- Step 2: On triggering a certain event, a $1 donation is automatically made to the charity from the user
- Step 3: A receipt generated back to the user, and also to the charity.

Step 2 would need to trigger each time the event happens, so although it could be $1, the event might happen 3 times, and therefore 3 payments would be made.

I'm looking at something like Stripe as the payment gateway provider, just not sure if I'm looking for the right kind of solution, and whether there is something else Ive not come across already.

Alternatively I would look at collating all occurrences of the event, and send a monthly payment link (**which appears to be much simpler approach**).

Any help would be appreciated, as Im looking to automate donations for a particular charity in the UK.

Very grateful for any advice anyone is willing to share. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Focusing on your overall goal, I believe you could use this [1] flow from Stripe which allows you to collect payment method information from your users and charge them later (whenever you want) by calling the API.

The idea here would be that whenever your "event" is triggered, you code calls the API and charges the saved payment method.

I can't provide a more thorough/specific suggestion since "event" term here is quite vague. Is this "event" time driven (like a subscription) OR something else?

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse

Comment: Thats awesome @hanzo, thankyou. Just having a pointer in the right direction is a brilliant start for me. 

Apologies, the 'event' is quite obscure, but triggering an API is exactly the idea Im looking to achieve.

Im still trying to determine the exact requirements of the event, but it would be some physical based interaction (such as pushing a button or something), that would trigger the API to make the single payment.

So if the user creates their account, sets up their payment details of say $1 and I call that each time they trigger it.

A brilliant start, thankyou!